# Navbar active link background not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

as you can see on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wftetf2r/5/), I'd like my active menu item to have a black rounded background (by "rounded" I mean similar to how it looks like with the hover effect).

For that purpose I have this piece of code

```
navbar-classic li a.active,
 .navbar-classic li a:hover {
   color: #fff;
   background: black;
 }
```

The issue is that even when I'm on index.html, my first menu item ("Index") still has a transparent background. Seems that li a.active is not taken into consideration.

What is the issue?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `.active` class is missing.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wftetf2r/7/)

```
<a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
```

Comment: Arghh, st*pid me, I should have spotted that! ;-/ Thanks a lot!